# shall I set a function which would run automatically when user open an existed record?

Tags: python, odoo

In the model, I have defined a function 'FOO'; a user creates a record 'X' of this model and saved it.

after that, I want the function 'FOO' would run automatically once the user opens the existed record 'X'; is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! I would recommend reading the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for information on how to ask a proper question that would inhibit other people to want to/be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They Have Two Options,

Option 1:

You can use `fields_view_get` method. Try below code maybe it helps you

```
@api.model
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False,
submenu=False):
    res = super(Project, self).fields_view_get(
    view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar,
    submenu=submenu)
    # add here your condition
    return res
```

Option 2:

You can use the compute method but in your case, this method not depends on any field mean you can use `@api.multi` in place of `@api.depends`

Thanks